# python - converting a set to a list

Tags: python, list, set

I am using python 3.4.5 to convert a set into a list 
The code I have used is as follow :

```
 def test(): 
        a = {1,2,3,4,5} 
        b = list(a)
```

However, I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 73, 
    b = list(a) 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list' referenced before assignment
```

Can I get some guidance as to how to resolve this ? is there some library that I should import to convert a set to a list ?

Comment: You have previously named a variable with name `list`. Restart your kernel and make sure you  don't do that again

Comment: I.e. there is nothing you can _do_ to make this work; but there is something you can _not_ do in order for this to work. (Never name a variable `list`, or `str`, or `dict`...) EDIT: actually, not true: you can still access the built-in `list` from `__builtins__.list(a)`... but that's hardly pretty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 73, 
    b = list(a) 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list' referenced before assignment
```

You named `list` as a variable or a function before.

Don't use `list` for your own variables or functions since it's the name of a built-in Python function.

Comment: run your code through pylint, it will complain about unfortunate variable names like this

Comment: thanks for the instruction ! I dont know how to run pylint I will read about it learn how to use it !